# Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

## Overview

I am trying to use Babel and Webpack to build a React app. I know I could use `create-react-app` but I'd like to learn how these technologies can work together for myself.

When I run `yarn run start` or `yarn run build` (see **package.json** below), Webpack reports to have built the bundle fine. When I run the application in the browser, I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` error.

There are a number of questions on SO regarding this same error, but none of the solutions have solved my problem yet.

## Question

What piece am I missing to get React, Babel, and Webpack to play together nicely?

## Code

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './dist'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  debug: true,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**src/index.js**

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

ReactDom.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**src/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>hello</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

## Observations

- It seems that Webpack/Babel is expecting `React` to be available on the global scope, or is ignoring my `import React from 'react';` statements.
- Also, I have yet to find the proper incantation of `devtools` and `debug` properties in my Webpack config to actually get source maps working. I don't yet see them in the compiled output.

### EDIT

The broken **bundle.js** is too large for SO (21,000+ lines), so here is a link: http://chopapp.com/#1a8udqpj — it takes several seconds to load and display.

Comment: I am wondering if you have a good reason not to use `.jsx` extensions for your JSX source code. Is it possible that it's causing some problems?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to see the content of your `bundle.js` file to understand where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: Can you post your project's directory structure?

Comment: This seems legit. Having a minimal broken bundle at this point would help.

Comment: @apendua, that's a good point but the React tutorials I've seen (including `create-react-app`) just use `.js`. I just tried it anyway to be sure, and it looks like that wasn't the problem.

Comment: @PaulStoner, sure, all files reside in the project's root, except `index.js` and `App.js`, which reside in `src/`.

Comment: @FilipDupanović I just edited the post to add a link to the broken bundle file.

Comment: @apendua see above comment ^

Comment: Shouldn't you include React before React-dom in your import statements?

Comment: @epascarello Good thought—just tried it that way and it didn't work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish to make the following observations. First to your question regarding devTools and debug. The debug flag for webpack (according to their [official documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#debug)) switches the loaders to debug mode. Then, from what I understand, webpack, when running in a dev environment, does not actually compile the code to hard files, but keeps it in memory. Thus the source maps are also kept in memory and linked to the browser. You see their effect when you open the browser dev tools and view source.

Now assuming you have the dev server configured correctly, I also assume your index.html is located in your source directory. If this is the case, then your script reference should simply point to '/bundle.js' and not 'dist/bundle.js' since there may not be a physical "dist" folder.

I would also suggest dropping the ".js" from your entry point in the webpack.config.js

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, the problem with source maps that I was trying to articulate was that they were either non-existent or not having any effect in Chrome's DevTools. As for index.html, it resides in the project's root, so `dist/index.js` is actually the correct path.

Comment: And unfortunately removing the `.js` from the webpack config's `entry` did not help.

Comment: So I just copied your code, verbatim, and recreated your project. As you have it, I receive a 404 error in Chrome when linking to dist/bundle.js. However, if I remove the "dist" and simply link to bundle, the app works fine and I see no messages in my console.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't have a 404 with bundle.js and it's definitely being loaded by the browser. But when I remove `dist/` like you said, it works! I'm guessing that `webpack-dev-server` automatically serves from the dist folder, or something? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well from my understanding, when working in dev mode, webpack does not actually compile files and write them out to disk. It keeps the everything in memory. Glad I could help

Comment: Ah OK. That's interesting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're trying to learn the in's and out's of webpack et al... Your original problem was that you needed to specify the `output.publicPath` in your webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './dist',
    publicPath: '/dist'  // <- was missing
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  debug: true,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

"`path`" is the physical path to the folder that contains your bundle.js. "`publicPath`" is the virtual path (URL) to that folder. So, you don't even have to use "dist". For example, if you used...

```
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './dist',
    publicPath: '/assets'
  },
```

Your HTML would then point to:

```
<script src="assets/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a query to your module within the webpack.config.js file:

```
module: {
loaders: [{
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
  }
}]
},
 resolve: {
   extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding the `query` attribute didn't help.